# Odoo TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I have this new field for hr holiday status model

```
class CodeLeaveType(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.holidays.status'

    code = fields.Char('Código para regla salarial', required=True)

    @api.one
    @api.onchange('code')
    def _check_code(self):
        pattern = "^[A-Z0-9]{3,6}$"
        if re.match(pattern, self.code) == None:
            self.code = ""
            return {
                'warning': {'title': 'Error',
                            'message': 'Formato de código para regla salarial no valido, debe incluir términos alfanúmeros en mayúsculas sin espacios, longitud máxima de caracteres 6', }
            }
```

But, when I try yo create a new holiday status get this error:

[image: e1]

Then when I close the error my onchange method **don't works normal** I get this error.

[image: e2]

I don't understand, plase help me. Maybe it's the regex?

I need a code only with uppercase or numbers with lenght between 3 and 6

**EDITED**

I change the regex by

```
class CodeLeaveType(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.holidays.status'

    code = fields.Char('Código para regla salarial', required=True)

    @api.multi
    @api.onchange('code')
    def _check_code(self):
        if self.code:
            pattern = "^[A-Z0-9]{3,6}$"
            if re.match(pattern, self.code) == None:
                self.code = ""
                return {
                    'warning': {'title': 'Error',
                                'message': 'Formato de código no valido, debe incluir términos alfanúmeros y guion (si aplica), longitud 3 a 6 caracteres', }
                }
```

And the method works normal !!! what is the cause for this error?

Comment: what  is `self.code`?

Comment: it's the new field that I added to hr holiday status

Comment: It should be string, but according to your stacktrace it's not

Comment: i'm sorry, i need edit the question

Comment: The second error is caused by the Frame work when you use `@api.one` the framework will call this method for every record in self and then collect the result in a list. with `onchange` event the client side expect a dictionary like the one you returned to know what to do with it. I think your code works now!! so what is the problem if it's not showing the error try to refresh the page sometimes the client side break

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@api.multi` code because you will be just interacting with just one record at a time.

Comment: You mean `@api.one` ?

Comment: No, @CZoellner I was refering to the edited code in the question which is using `@api.multi`

Comment: But multi should be okay. One is returning a list of methods results, which results in the AttributeError (second one).